# How to overwrite merge method in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to tweak merge method in pandas for my needs. Basically I need to check if merge doesnt lead to multiplying rows and if it does, write appropriate info to my logger. I can edit pandas source code but this is obviously not the proper way to do it.

I tried to create own merge method with exending DataFrame class and monkey patch merge in my modules like:

```
pd.DataFrame = myDataFrameWithCustomMerge
```

This works if I create df's with pd.DataFrame() constructor, but this doesnt overwrite merge for my dataframes, since I create them using `pd.read_sql()` or `pd.read_excel()` syntax.

I also tried to modify `sys.module['pandas']` to overwrite DataFrame globally, but this didnt work neither. The only way I found is to overwrite merge in source files.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new class that inherits from `pd.DataFrame`:

```
class NoMergeDf(pd.DataFrame):
    def merge():
        print('Overriding!')

df = NoMergeDf(pd.read_excel(path))
df.merge() # prints 'Overriding!'
```

**EDIT**

if you don't want to refactor everything you can create a module called `pd2`:

```
import pandas as pd

class NoMergeDf(pd.DataFrame):
    def merge():
        print('Overriding!')

def read_sql(*args, **kwargs):
    return NoMergeDf(pd.read_sql(*args, **kwargs))

def read_excel(*args, **kwargs):
    return NoMergeDf(pd.read_excel(*args, **kwargs))
```

Then you only need to change the places where `read_sql` and `read_excel` are called.

**EDIT 2**

I just realized the above means wrapping every other DataFrame method as well, because any reassignment like `df = df[[col1, col2]]` will revert `df` to a pandas DataFrame.

The solution that causes the least pain is to write a custom `merge(df1, df2)` that does what you want, then just refactor the parts where you invoke `DataFrame.merge`.

Comment: Thanks for answer! As I mentioned I did this, but this doesnt resolve issue when I create DataFrame from pd.read_sql() and pd.read_excel(). It also requires to refactor code in my entire project.

Comment: it works for me... what's not working on your side? `df = NoMergeDf(pd.read_excel(path))` converts it to a `NoMergeDf`

Comment: It works but I need refactor all of my application code in order to do this. If its only way I would probably stick with it.

Comment: for the sanity of anyone else looking at your code, you probably shouldn't change pandas :P